# Magento SOAP API: wsdl soap:address location incorrect

Tags: api, magento, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to a Magento instance using the SOAP API v2, and although I can see the wsdl when I visit http://www.domain.loc/api/v2_soap?type=soap&wsdl=1  in my browser, I am unable to execute the login() call, an error is always thrown.

Code:

```
$options = array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    //'location' =>   'http://www.domain.loc/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'connection_timeout' => 120,
    'exception' => 0,
    'encoding' => 'utf-8',
);
try {

    $client = new soapClient('http://www.domain.loc/api/v2_soap?type=soap&wsdl=1', $options);
    $client->login('username', 'password');
    //$result = $client->catalogProductList($sessionId);
    //$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');
    var_dump($client);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Which yields "SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document"
When I uncomment the location option I get "SoapFault: Wrong Version"
When I view the wsdl file, I see the soap:address location set as

```
<port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
<soap:address location="http://www.domain.loc/index.php/?SID=7o7mn7iiu9tr8u1b9163r305d4dp1l1jrcn1hmnr34utgnhgb6i0&type=soap"/>
```

Which seems incorrect as it is the URL to the homepage, with the SID and a query param.

Magento version EE1.14
Things I have tried:

- Disable local modules - no change
- Using Zend_Soap_Client - no change
- Various different URL configurations - tried everything under the
  sun, no change
- Using SOAP v1 - same results
- Tried using this on a remote instance instead of my local - same
  result
- Checked phpinfo - yes SOAP is installed
- Tried debugging - When I turn on Xdebug and run my test script it
  seems to prevent the script from even running. Browser just
  indicates loading forever
- Tried to uncomment line in .htaccess to rewrite `RewriteRule
  ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]` - No change
  (yes mod rewrite is on and working)
- Tried fetching wsdl and saving locally and passing it into SOAP
  client constructor - no change

Anyone know how to troubleshoot this? I see several threads with these errors, but either unanswered or have tried their solution and it did not work in this case. Why is my location in the wsdl incorrect? Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I think I've got the same issue.